# i have to know "how to run Pl SQL Procedure within the packege based on prioritywise?

Tags: oracle11g

I have to create a mapplet, it consists of many procedures. 
I need to run procedures one by one in priority order which is in table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE VISION_DQ.PR_TEST_MPLT (TR_ID        NUMBER,
                                                    SEQ_ORDER    NUMBER)
IS
   PROMPT_SEQ   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   PROMPT_SEQ := SEQ_ORDER;

   FOR I IN 1 .. PROMPT_SEQ
   LOOP
      IF (I = TR_ID)
      THEN
         PR_CHR ('cd', 'T1');
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace);
END;
/
```

Comment: Sounds like you're going to need dynamic SQL. If you want a better answer than that, please edit your question to include a test case of what you're trying to achieve. It can be a example test case, e.g. with a dummy table, dummy code, etc, but it does need to demonstrate all scenarios that may occur.

Comment: Maybe you can store the procedure calls in required order in the table. Query the table and get the Procedure call and execute it.

Comment: Maplletid col derived_col strtgy table Transformationid Seq Quer_select Quer_from Quer_where Quer_order Quer_group Query
========================================================
1211 col1 n  t1 1 1      
1211 col2 n  t1 1 1      
1211 col3 y upper(col1) t1 4 2      
1211 col4 y loer(col2) t1 3 3
=======================================================